# Using localhost as Canvas URL doesnt work

Tags: java, facebook, canvas, permissions, restfb

I'm trying to develop a simple desktop application to publish posts on my wall using `restfb` api for Java. It works fine so far, but other users cant see my posts, only me. After reading some other documentation, I found out that an HTTP request like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream
```

is used to edit the publicity settings of my applications. As I mentioned before, it's a local desktop application without any webserver behind it, so I want to use the localhost as a canvas URL, because its needed in the link above. I simply used `http://localhost:8080/` as my site-, canvas- and secure canvas url. After using these informations in the HTTP request above  I get the error, that the requested link doesnt work. My posts still can't be read by others.

Do you have any suggestions to solve that problem?

Comment: The URL should be that with which you have registered you app key, I seem to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  A little more to add.

> (1) I'm taking ownership of an iOS app that has apparently had this
>   problem (not sure when it started).
>
> (2) When the "app Settings" has been created for the first time (i.e.,
>   once permissions were granted and the "app Settings" appear on my
>   Facebook Account Settings -> App Settings page), the App activity
>   privacy field is set to Only Me.
>
> (3) Setting it manually to Friends
>   on my Facebook account still does not allow it to post to anything
>   other than "Only Me".

**Update**: I got it to work by changing the Default Privacy setting under Privacy Settings of my personal Facebook account - the one to which my app was posting.  I had it set to Custom with "Only Me" selected. That would be a good FAQ item for our apps.  I guess we can think of that setting as a global override.

Answer (score 0):

Your local host can only be used inside you machine once you are working with facebook you most provide them a global url.

Try replacing localhost with [your ip](http://www.whatismyip.com/)